# ASP.NET update Panel losses dyamically added controls on ImageButton Click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, imagebutton

greeting programs,

Im working on app that queries another website, and pulls back an xml, I then populate a result panel with ImageButton(s), and time in a click event, when the image is click I want to popup a div box using the jquery ui, that will show more information, about the picture clicked on. however whenever id this this seems to wipe out my results panel(Panel Control) and the div box never appears and as far as I can tell the imagebutton click event never fires. I've tried doing this two ways one with an update panel and again without, I would appreciate any help on this.Im wondering if I'm doing to much long on my search button click, Im wonder if I should just let the post pack handle populating the result panel and ditch the update panel.

(and yes my div tag is set to runat server)

I'm also up for suggestions maybe there is a better way to do this, I thought creating hidden div tags for each item, and then running javascript for when the image is clicked and showing it that way, However that seems stupid, in my opinion it seems to make more sense to make my div control once and then update the labels inside it on each image click and then show or hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code if I had to guess I would say that a post back occurs and wipes out all of your data since that doesn't match whatever viewstate may think things should have.  If you're using jQuery and jQuery UI on the page already I would suggest you also do your "more information popup" with jquery.

If you already have the information on the page and you're just trying to show it to the user why bother using an imagebutton's onclick function.

Comment: Yea, I think your right that its the post back wiping it, that being said I tried stopping it by doing if(IsPostBack) return;, that didn't seem to work. But yea basically the problem is I just want to display an image to the user, and then when they click on it I want to show them more information about it and possible some db action. I would try tying this all into the client side, but the server has data i need, so ideally i would create the dlg on page load, and populate the fields when i click the image and then show it to the user.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you do if(IsPostBack) return;  You've still left the page you were on and there isn't any state to http.  Its going to start from scratch again.  You can try and get webmethod results from client side code or call a webservice to get the data.  Or give the server data to the client in advance as json objects.  Just because the view shows the information on click doesn't mean the code has to get it then.

Comment: How come the update panel doesn't work, I mean I would think if the controls where inside a update panel, the post back would be counteracted?